# Using latex to color variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, latex, mathjax

I have the following line in my javascript running, which will format a cubic equation in latex/mathjax to display, while including variables from the code:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "$y = $" + xzero + "$ + $" + xone + "$x + $" + xtwo + "$x^2 + $" + xthree + "$x^3$";
```

What I want to do now is color the part of the equation where the variable is. I thought something like

```
...= "$y = \color{#AF0}{$" + roundNum(xzero) + "$} + $"...
```

would work, but it seems evident that it does not. Could I get some help on how I could color the variables in my equation?

Comment: What are you seeing? How about a live code sample? Also, you probably need to drop the inner $. But without more information, it's hard to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you do this after your line of code that sets innerHTML of #demo?

```
MathJax.Callback.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, "demo"]);
```

At me,

```
"$y = \\color{#AF0}{" + roundNum(xzero) + "} + "... +"$";
```

worked, and remove dollar signs in the midle of the equation, put them only at the start and the end (like I did).

This is how it should look like:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "$y = \\color{#AF0}{" + roundNum(xzero) + "} + "... +"$";
MathJax.Callback.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, "demo"]);
```

**EDIT:**

I doubled the backslashes like @Davide Cervone said.

Comment: There is also a problem with the backslashes, which must be doubled in order to get them to be part of the string literal:  `... = "$ y = \\color{#AF0}{"...`

Comment: Just a quick question, but in my code I'm already using the line 
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, 'demo']) . Is there any reason why your typeset might be any better or worse than the one I'm already using?